# intellij logcat display json object just "[object]", how can I display the whole json object?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sencha-touch, android-logcat

I'm using sencha touch , with node.js as a complier, debug in  intellij IDE.
and I have 3 question with the environment:
Here is the log in logcat.

**11-21 09:48:18.309: INFO/Web Console(6076): result  [object]  at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:1**

1、Can't display the whole json object ,what I expect is something like : result:{'val':'123', 'val2':'456'}

2、Console.log('result ', result) ----- this is not from app.js and the line is not line 1. (compressed?), How can I see the real file and the real line.

3、My project is complier as node.js , and open the folder as a web project, so I can't see the android logcat. I need to open another android project to see the logcat.

any suggection is appreciated. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a long journey for a console.log to be displayed in the Android Log. I'd suggest you output JSON objects with `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
2. Probably a compressed JavaScript. Use uncompressed for testing (Grunt!)
3. I think you can just change to the Android view. If this is not possible, include your Android project as a module of your Web-Project.